# Access to web.config attributes (not appSettings)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

given that I can add various attributes to the stock membership provider I assume I can do the same with my own provider implementation.

```
<add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="Portal.Infrastructure.MyMembershipProvider"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                enablePasswordReset="true"
                requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
                [...] />
```

My question now: How do I access these values in the code? I understand that the ConfigurationManager can be used to access key value pairs in the appSettings section but this is different.

Comment: IMHO  should not these be available by default on your provider class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what section you trying to acces but genearl idea is that you can access WebConfig directly by:

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(configPath);  
// Get the object related to the <identity> section.
IdentitySection section = (IdentitySection)config.GetSection("system.web/identity");
```

Instead of IdentitySection put your section.